# How can I regulate voltage with multiple AC motors?

Tags: voltage, induction-motor, surge-protection

I have a water treatment system that has several motors and pumps from blowers for aeration to submersible 3hp water pumps. A lot of these motors have to be repaired and replaced often, sometimes 2 times per year. The engineer says it's because of the voltage spikes from inconsistent power.

I'm aware that these motors being inductive can cause voltage drops when they turn on and spikes when they turn off. Is there any particular way to regulate that? I suppose a heavy duty surge suppressor (like the whole house variety) would help suppress the spikes. Is there anything to help with the dips? Or is it only the spikes that are harmful? Or are voltage spikes not even the likely cause here?

Comment: The electric side being easy to monitor, the first measure would be to *log* extraordinary operating parameters. 3hp is just a bit low to expect overload relays ("Motorschutzschalter"). With the level of detail about the damages I'd need a crystal ball, but induction machines are almost as prone to failures as transformers.

Answer (score 1):

I find it a little surprising that spikes are damaging an induction motor.  They are just windings. It would appear as arcing damage - soot and damage from insulation breakdown.

I don't really see voltage sags causing a problem unless they are lasting a long time, in which case it would be evident as thermal damage - cooked insulation and annealed wires.

However if you want to suppress spikes, yes, surge suppressors are readily available for home wiring, and if you're in Europe, home wiring is the same stuff as commercial wiring by and large (at least in Germany where most people get all 3 phases).  They are not costly.

Comment: Considering the number of parties in communicating the circumstances, what results from *inconsistent power* may as well be *current surges* (think *unbalanced 3phase*), and while *3hp* suggests *induction motor*, I wouldn't read *motors being inductive* to spell it out, not even tagging so.

Comment: I'm still trying to get detail from the manufacturer as to what goes wrong (they sometimes replace them under warranty) so maybe it's just the bearings.

Comment: @greybeard since you brought it up, some of these motors are 240v but we have 2 legs of a 3 phase grid. If the two phases are 120 degrees instead of 180 would that make a difference?

Comment: @DAB I wouldn't expect so.  In North America the motor is typically wired line-line so it is 208V, and in Europe a single-phase motor is probably wired line-neutral for 230/240V.